# Copy data to a sheet with four rows separating each cell from the original sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I take row entries from one sheet (i.e. data) and paste them onto another sheet (i.e. calculate) with three rows between the pasted cells?

I could copy and paste but that would be so tedious. Looking for a formula or VBA code.

[image: Data sheet]

[image: Calculate shee]

Answer (score 1):

If
Sheet1 is your source sheet
Sheet2 is your destination sheet
Then the VBA code is :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100 'number of rows 

 Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(((i - 1) * 4) + 1, 1)

Next i

End Sub
```

Hope this helps